# How to check a data that is not null in a database

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my python code. I want to find the column called `program_id` in a database as I want to check if they don't have the null data so I can select and fetch the data I want for each channel.

When I try this:

```
for index in range(0, CHANNELS_PER_PAGE):
    channel = channels_list[index]
    channel_index = index

    #get the programs list
    cur.execute('SELECT title, start_date, stop_date, program_id FROM programs WHERE program_id!=NULL LIMIT 10')
```

It wont let me to find the `program_id` data in a database as it will only find the `program_id` data that is null. I want to find the `program_id` data in a database that is not null.

Can you please show me an example how I can fetch the `program_id` data from the database that is not null for per channel?

Comment: `WHERE program_id IS NOT NULL LIMIT 10`

Comment: I have already try it, but it wont find the values for `program_id` that is not null. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot `WHERE program_id<>''`

What database engine are you using?

```
#get the programs list
    cur.execute('SELECT title, start_date, stop_date, program_id FROM programs WHERE program_id<>'' LIMIT 10')
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting an error `Error Contents: near "LIMIT": syntax error`

Comment: > "What database engine are you using?"

Comment: i am using sqlite3 sorry

Comment: Ah, sqlite, try `WHERE program_id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: still the same, any idea?

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/is_not_null.php 
Are you sure the fields are NULL? I've had a single space in the field look like NULL in things like SQL Workbench.

Comment: yes i am sure that but I want to look for the fields that are NOT null. Like this: https://i.imgur.com/c2VMwuy.jpg

Comment: So I created a DB with a similar schema. I am able to utilize my original query to select the NOT NULL values, i.e. `SELECT * FROM example WHERE program_id<>''`. That's 2 `'` with nothing in between. As for your last question, I am able to select items of 3001 and 3002 with the following: `SELECT * FROM example WHERE program_id LIKE '3001' OR program_id LIKE '3002'`. I hope that helps.